# Change font size for annotation_custom()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used annotation_custom() to add text below my plot. However, I cannot figure out how to decrease the font size.Desperately, I tried `geom_text(size= 8)` which did not work & `annotation_custom(size=8)` does not take a 'size' argument. How do you change the font size of annotation_custom()?

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2)))
p= ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
   geom_point()+
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1), "cm"))+
   ggtitle('Random Plot')

Text1 = textGrob('Additional suggestions:')
p1 = p + annotation_custom(grob = Text1,  xmin = 0.2, xmax = 0.2, ymin = -0.3, ymax = -0.3)
    
gt <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

Any info would be super helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `textGrob`? You can just do `annotate("text")`, which takes a `size` argument to set the text size

Comment: Yes, I did not use `annotate('text')` as I wanted to add text outside of my plot & as far as I am aware annotate() does not allow to do so.

Comment: You can set `gp = gpar(fontsize = 10)` inside `textGrob`

Comment: You can use `annotate(geom = "text", label = ..., size = ...)`, and remove the clipping (as you did). Make sure you put the extra `margin` on the correct side though, here the left (`plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 4), "cm")`)

Comment: Thanks @camille , exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Camille in the comments, you could use the `gp` argument with `gpar(fontsize=8)` of the `annotation_custom` function like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:100), y=sort(rexp(100, 2)))
p= ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point()+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1), "cm"))+
  ggtitle('Random Plot')

Text1 = textGrob('Additional suggestions:', gp = gpar(fontsize=8))
p1 = p + annotation_custom(grob = Text1,  xmin = 0.2, xmax = 0.2, ymin = -0.3, ymax = -0.3)

gt <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the `annotate` function from `ggplot2`. Make sure you `clip` the coordinations using `coord_cartesian`. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
p= ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point()+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1), "cm"))+
  ggtitle('Random Plot') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$x), max(df$x)),
                  ylim = c(min(df$y), max(df$y)), clip = "off") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.2, y = -0.3, label = "Additional suggestions:", size = 5)
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>